# Execute stored procedure error in select statement

Tags: oracle11g

I have a Procedure like this,

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_PROOF
( proof_id IN NUMBER
, Type1 IN VARCHAR2
, StatementType IN NUMBER
, Resultset OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  IF StatementType = 1 Then

INSERT INTO ID_Proof (proofid,Id_type) 
VALUES (proof_id, Type1); 
ELSIF StatementType=2 THEN
SELECT  proofid,Id_type Into Resultset FROM ID_Proof;
ELSIF StatementType=3 THEN
UPDATE ID_Proof SET Id_type =  Type1 WHERE proofid = proof_id;

ELSIF StatementType=4 THEN
 DELETE FROM ID_Proof WHERE proofid = proof_id;

 end if;
 end;
```

Im getting an error like this,
Error(14,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(14,64): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Please help me to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

Line 14 is:

```
SELECT  proofid,Id_type Into Resultset FROM ID_Proof;
```

You are selecting two values, `proofid` and `Id_type`, into a single scalar variable `Resultset`. But you also have no filter, so even if you changed that to select a single value then you'd get a too-many-rows error if there was more than one row in the table (and no-data-found if the table is empty).

It isn't clear what you want to happen; perhaps you want `select id_type into resultset from id_proof`, but from the parameters `id_type` is a string - so selecting that into a number variable is likely to fail too. Or perhaps you want all IDs for the specified type, in which case the type of `result set` would need to be a table type or a ref cursor.

Having separate procedures and functions would be probably be clearer, too.